# What effect do Strionic Resonator and Vorinclex, Voice of Hunger have together?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d) and a [Vorinclex, Voice of Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVorinclex%2c%20Voice%20of%20Hunger%5d) in play under my control, what will happen when I tap a land for mana, or when my opponent taps a land for mana?

Answer (score 8):

You can't use Strionic Resonator when you tap a land for mana. Mana abilities do not use the stack. According to rule 605.1, a mana ability is an activated ability that creates mana, or a triggered ability that triggers off of mana creation and makes more mana itself (such as with Overgrowth or the last ability on Gauntlet of Power). Since Vorinclex's ability is never on the stack, you can't target it.

If you copy the second ability, it won't have any additional effect. The ability doesn't have any targets, it simply affects the same land twice during the next untap step (my comment below indicating that this may not be the case is wrong).

Comment: It would be useful to add text to answer OP's second question, as the second triggered ability on Vorinclex is not a mana ability and therefore can be targeted by Strionic Resonator. (Chad's answer includes this but also misses that the first triggered ability is a mana ability.)

Comment: I was going too, but I'm not sure Chad's answer is correct. I believe the affected land skips two untap steps. I'll edit that in when I find the correct rule reference.

Comment: It would if the untap step were skipped, but that's not what the ability does, it just says that the affected land doesn't untap during that step.

Answer (score 1):

It more or less does nothing. Neither trigger targets, and each triggers separately for each land, so you could only copy a trigger for one land. And as a mana ability, the first trigger doesn't use the stack and can't be targeted anyway. So the only thing you could do with it is make it so that a land that doesn't untap next untap step also doesn't untap next untap step (which is redundant and completely useless unless there's some corner case I'm missing)